# Change logging level in redisson

Tags: redis, redisson

I have just started with testing redisson client to connect to redis. By default it uses Debug level logging and writes a lot of logs. How can I increase the level of logging to INFO? I am using spring boot application and I have tried to set logging.level.root=INFO in my application.properties file which does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added to my logback.xml

```
<logger name="org.redisson" level="INFO" />
```